# python How can I parse html and print specific output inside html tag

Tags: python, html, parsing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
import requests, bs4

    res = requests.get('https://betaunityapi.webrootcloudav.com/Docs/APIDoc/APIReference')
    web_page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

    for d in web_page.findAll("div",{"class":"actionColumnText"}):
        print d
```

Result:

```
<div class="actionColumnText">
<a href="/Docs/APIDoc/Api/POST-api-console-gsm-gsmKey-sites-siteId-endpoints-reactivate">/service/api/console/gsm/{gsmKey}/sites/{siteId}/endpoints/reactivate</a>
</div>
<div class="actionColumnText">
Reactivates a list of endpoints, or all endpoints on a site.        </div>
```

I am interested to see output with only the last line (*Reactivates a list of endpoints, or all endpoints on a site*) removing start  and end .
Not interested in the line with *href*

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a simple case, you can just [get the text](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
for d in web_page.find_all("div", {"class": "actionColumnText"}):
    print(d.get_text())
```

Or/and, if there is only single element you want to find, you can get the last match by index:

```
d = web_page.find_all("div", {"class": "actionColumnText"})[-1]
print(d.get_text())
```

Or, you can also find `div` elements with a specific class which don't have an `a` child element:

```
def filter_divs(elm):
    return elm and elm.name == "div" and "actionColumnText" in elm.attrs and elm.a is None 

for d in web_page.find_all(fitler_divs):
    print(d.get_text())
```

Or, in case of a single element:

```
web_page.find(fitler_divs).get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

U can select the last one with a CSS selector:

```
var d = web_page.select("div.actionColmnText:last")
d.string()
```

Answer (score 0):

If this text changes you can use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
import requests, bs4

    res = requests.get('https://betaunityapi.webrootcloudav.com/Docs/APIDoc/APIReference')
    web_page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

    yourText = web_page.findAll("div",{"class":"actionColumnText"})[-1]
    yourText = yourText.split('  ')[0]
```